# Detecting device orientation change using android:screenOrientation

Tags: android, webview, screen-orientation

Is there a way to detect device orientation events or at least to
get the current device orientation while using
android:screenOrientation in the manifest ?
I mean device orientation not application orientation.

My problem is I **really** want to keep my application in portait mode
(it's a web view) but I want to handle orientation change myself in my
app. When android:screenOrientation is setted, orientation getted by
methods is always the application orientation, not the device
orientation.

Regards,
Gaëtan

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use the acelerometer to detect the device orientation. I know, it's more hard but I think is the only solution.

[Android | Sensor Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html)

[Android | Sensor Manager | getOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29)

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle device rotation yourself, then use the following method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
    Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
    {           
        mFlash.startAnimation(mRotate);
    }
    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
    {
        parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);                           
    }

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
    {
        parameters.setPreviewSize(height, width);               
    }

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
    {
        parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
    }

}
```

The actions inside the if statements are just examples of what might be done. Obviously, handle whatever you need to there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the nice orientation (portrait or landscape) values that you get will always give you "application orientation". For device orientation you can check out [SensorManager.getOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29).

Unfortunately the method for listening to changes in this value is marked deprecated, so you may need to poll periodically.